# We are both identical and contrary

Tags: riddle, word, knowledge

Our head has two parts

- The first part doesn't go well with Paris and should watch what they drink.
- The second part may not be silent but doesn't have anything new to say.
- Together, they are a drop of golden sun.

Our trunk has three parts

- The first part was originally into livestock but these days favors Italian sports cars.
- The second part either likes zigzag shirts or hat & cane.
- The third part doesn't actually call for a rose in teeth.
- It's not usually desirable to get caught in their concatenation.

Our tail has four parts

- The first part is big--but not quite a continent--and likes writing.
- The second part is either a grouch or prestigious depending on who you ask.
- The third part is thankfully remembered for its 4th or 5th.
- The fourth part is known for both saws and forests, both mountains and valleys.
- Together the four parts are invariably an optimist or pessimist, never simply neutral.

Put together, we are both identical and contrary. What are we?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The head, trunk, and tail are each composed of a certain number of 'part's. Each part is a letter and is clued by its word from the NATO phonetic alphabet.

> Our head has two parts
>
> - The first part doesn't go well with Paris and should watch what they drink.

> ROMEO doesn't get along with Count Paris and should not drink poison.

> - The second part may not be silent but doesn't have anything new to say.

> Some E's are silent but ECHOS just repeat.

> - Together, they are a drop of golden sun.

> RE, the musical note which is described as a golden drop of sun in the song Do-Re-Mi from The Sound of Music.

> Our trunk has three parts
>
> - The first part was originally into livestock but these days favors Italian sports cars.

> ALFA comes from the Greek letter alpha which comes from the Phoenician letter aleph which is the West Semitic word for "ox". ALFA Romeo is an Italian sports car company

> - The second part either likes zigzag shirts or hat & cane.

> CHARLIE Brown or CHARLIE Chaplin

> - The third part doesn't actually call for a rose in teeth.

> Some people have a rose in their teeth when they dance the TANGO.

> - It's not usually desirable to get caught in their concatenation.

> It's not usually desirable to get caught in the ACT.

> Our tail has four parts
>
> - The first part is big--but not quite a continent--and likes writing.

> INDIA is big but not quite a continent. There is also INDIA ink.

> - The second part is either a grouch or prestigious depending on who you ask.

> OSCAR the grouch. OSCAR movie award.

> - The third part is thankfully remembered for its 4th or 5th.

> Thanksgiving is celebrated in the USA on the 4th Thursday in NOVEMBER. We remember remember the fifth of NOVEMBER for Guy Fawkes Day.

> - The fourth part is known for both saws and forests, both mountains and valleys.

> SIERRA is Spanish for saw. There are also SIERRA National Forest, SIERRA Nevada mountains and SIERRA valley.

> - Together the four parts are invariably an optimist or pessimist, never simply neutral.

> IONS are positive or negative, never neutral.

> Put together, we are both identical and contrary. What are we?

> REACTIONS. for every action there is an equal and opposite reaction.

Comment: Correct!! ROT13: GUR NAFJRE VF IREL PBZCERURAFVIR, BAYL QRGNVY GB NQQ VF GUNG SBE "4GU NAQ 5GU" ERSREERQ GB OBGU GUNG UBYVQNL BA GUR 4GU GUHEFQNL NAQ 5GU (THL SNJXRF QNL = ERZRZORE, ERZRZORE GUR ...), "FNJ" ERSRERAPR JNF GB BAR ZRNAVAT BS GUNG JBEQ VA FCNAVFU, NAQ GUR BEVTVA BS N PREGNVA YRGGRE VF VA GUR JBEQ "BK" (V QVQ ABG XABJ NOBHG GUR NHFGENYVNA YBG SRRQREF, GUNG VF NA VAGRERFGVAT PBVAPVQRAPR).

Comment: @C8H10N4O2 Oh cool, I'll fix those. Also what is the connection between rot13(Vaqvn naq jevgvat)?

Comment: That connection is Vaqvn vax. Also, Bfpne unf n frpbaq cerfgvtvbhf zrnavat.